# Firefox OS app not displaying after deployment to Panasonic TV

Tags: web-applications, firefox-os

I have created a simple Firefox OS app and succesfully deployed it to a Panasonic TV using the Firefox WebIDE.
The app appears in the apps page and it runs succesfully. However the icon is missing.

I have used the following manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "my app",
    "description": "just a simple one page app",
    "version": "1.0",
    "launch_path": "/path/Default.aspx",
    "icons": {
        "16": "/path/Images/icon-16.png",
        "48": "/path/Images/icon-48.png",
        "128": "/path/Images/icon-128.png",
        "336": "/path/Images/icon-336.png",
        "512": "/path/Images/icon-512.png"
    },
    "fullscreen": true
}
```

All icon files are present at the given location. Can anyone tell how to get the icon appear on the apps page on my TV?

Comment: The icons in your manifest look right to me. Sounds like you should file a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox%20OS Component= Gaia::TV::Home

Comment: I filed a bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1192848
Now wait and see.